# Accidental corrupted recovery mode partition and cannot longer boot to it

Tags: startup, recovery, dual-boot

I recently installed Ubuntu in a partition of my hard drive in a MacBook Pro (Early 2011) running macOS Sierra. My recovery partition was corrupted in the process and I cannot longer access recovery mode. Internet Recovery works fine, but it is the original recovery that came with my mac (OS X Lion Recovery) and I cannot disable SIP from there since Lion did not support it. What should I do?

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r show disk0` entered in Terminal.app to your question by [editing](http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/269552/edit) it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by [creating a bootable USB macOS installer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) with `createinstallmedia` from terminal. Then I booted from it and disabled System Integrity Protection and installed Refind from there. I tried booting to Recovey HD from Refind and it worked just fine.